Is this crack in my concrete floor a structural concern?
I've been removing all the tile, and then progressing to removing all the screed layer, and I made this crack on the floor in my bedroom on the first floor.
I am unsure if it's structural. It feels hollow and empty when I stomp on it. When I look closely, it doesn't feel like anything is under the crack. It just feels empty.
Is it structural? How do I fix it?


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

It is important to know how the floor was constructed. That will determine if there is a reason to worry.
In many condo and apartment buildings it is common for the floors to be poured concrete in a metal supporting pan. Cracks, such as you have are not uncommon and no reason to worry.
As others have mentioned there may be a thin leveling layer on the top of a wood framed floor. A thin crack, again would be no issue.
If this is slab on grade, I would be amazed if there were no cracks in the concrete.
The signs of a problem would be cracks that are separated in 2 different plains, or a noticeable rise or dip in one section as opposed to another. If your floor is flat and the concrete is not crumbling, you are ok.  If you have any of the other issues, you should have an evaluation done by a professional familiar with poured concrete floors.
